# How to create a vector that saves elements of all types of the same template class

Tags: c++, templates, types, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have a template class:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class blah{...};
```

I want to create a std::vector<> to save any possible objects of blah.

for example

```
blah<float, int, string>
```

or

```
blah<string, string, char>
```

those blah objects, although originated from the same template class, are essentially different types. How can I declare a std::vector to save them all?

I thought about using std::variant, but I can't because to use it, I need to enumerate all possible template parameter combinations:

```
std::variant<all possible template parameter combinations>
```

I thought about using std::any, I can't because I don't know how to type cast from std::any back to the right type?

I thought about using a base class:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class blah : public blah_base
{...};
```

and declare a vector like this:

```
std::vector<blah_base*>
```

but again, I still don't know how to type cast from blah_base* back to the right type?

Comment: How do you use the `blah<...>` instances? What is your use-case? Can't you solve it with inheritance and virtual functions? What is the *actual* problem you try to solve?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `bla` or is it too long?

Comment: I'm trying to implement deep learning neuron network. The blah type is the tensor. a tensor could have different dimension, device types and data types.  so the real blah is defined as  "template<int Dimension = 4, DeviceType DeviceUsed = GPU, typename DataType = float> class {...};"

Comment: To be honest, I don't think my use case matters. I just want to simplify my problem with a dummy class. but if you really want to know the code, you can see it here: https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/tree/master/guide#tensor-data-structure

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you need is polymorphism. All of the options you were exploring are polymorphism, and that is the best way for this to be solved. However, you say this and other variations:

> I don't know how to type cast from blah_base* back to the right type

If you find yourself needing to do this, you are doing something wrong. Either it doesn't make sense to have a `std::vector<blah<...>>`, or your blahs all need to meet the blah_base contract.

You could solve this with a virtual function:

```
class blah_base {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Then, rather than having to tell which type of `blah` you had, you'd just call the appropriate `foo` function that does what you want.

Comment: I don't think "I'm doing something wrong". I think C++ lacks the "reflection" feature, that's why. https://root.cern.ch/blog/status-reflection-c

Comment: see this. it's not clear to me if c++1z has reflection. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8651990

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing too much about what your use case is I will assume you will have three vectors; one for each template type. You could implement `blah` as such:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class blah
{
public:
    // Put stuff here.
    void AddToVectorA(A item);
    void AddToVectorB(B item);
    void AddToVectorC(C item);
private:
    std::vector<A> _a;
    std::vector<B> _b;
    std::vector<C> _c;
};

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
void blah<A,B,C>::AddToVectorA(A item)
{
    _a.push_back(item);
}

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
void blah<A,B,C>::AddToVectorB(B item)
{
    _b.push_back(item);
}

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
void blah<A,B,C>::AddToVectorC(C item)
{
    _c.push_back(item);
}

int main()
{
    blah<int, double, float> b;
    b.AddToVectorA(2);

    return 0;
}
```

You could also make the three vectors public and people can use them however; you could also look into `tuple`. FYI: I now tested the code, it works.

Comment: My trouble is the combination of types is huge, I will need to have many vectors, not just 3.